# Implementing CardLayout within a JFrame and switching cards based on specific button presses

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I've posted my code below. I have the simple task of creating a navigable GUI. I've spent the past few hours doing research on how to accomplish this, and this is the code that I've put together.

Originally I wanted to perform the navigation without any layouts or anything. I need the home panel to display after the user clicks on the "login" button on the welcome panel.

It displays the welcome card just fine, but when I get to the validateLogin method(which is activated when the login button is press, and upon successful login it should show the home panel within cards) it simply stays on the welcome panel even though I have validated that my program reaches the loop to change cards via the system.out.Println()

Please help. I spent my entire Saturday trying to solve this one problem through trials and research, but with no success. This is a last resort for me so if anyone can show me my flaws then I'll happily be on my way and fix it. Then apply that fix to the many other cards that are required for my program.

```
    enter code here
    public class mainGUI implements ActionListener{
JFrame main;
JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());

//Items for the welcome panel
JPanel welcome = welcomePanel();
JButton login;
JButton register;
JTextField username;
JTextField password;

//home panel
JPanel home = homePanel();


//WelcomePanel welcome = new WelcomePanel();

ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student workingStudent;


/**
 * calls load() at start and save() on exit
 * 
 */
public mainGUI(){
    load();

    main = new JFrame();
    main.setSize(900, 600);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setTitle("MyCourses 2k16");
    main.setContentPane(welcomePanel());

    //fill out the cards
    cards.add(welcome, "Welcome");
    cards.add(home, "Home");
            //display welcome card
    cl.show(cards, "welcome");

    main.setVisible(true);

    saveState();
}

private JPanel welcomePanel() {
    JPanel welcome = new JPanel();
    welcome.setLayout(null);
    welcome.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JLabel hi = new JLabel("Welcome to MyCourses 2K16");
    hi.setSize(800, 100);
    hi.setLocation(50,50);
    hi.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 48));
    hi.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JLabel select = new JLabel("Fill in the information, then click login or register to proceed, no special characters allowed");
    select.setSize(700,100);
    select.setLocation(75,100);
    select.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    select.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    login = new JButton( "login");
    login.setSize(100, 50);
    login.setLocation(50, 200);
    login.addActionListener(this);

    register = new JButton( "register");
    register.setSize(100,50);
    register.setLocation(200, 200);
    register.addActionListener(this);

    JLabel un = new JLabel("username");
    un.setSize(100, 30);
    un.setLocation(50, 270);
    un.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    username = new JTextField();
    username.setSize(200, 30);
    username.setLocation(50,300);

    JLabel pw = new JLabel("password");
    pw.setSize(100, 30);
    pw.setLocation(50, 350);
    pw.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    password = new JTextField();
    password.setSize(200, 30);
    password.setLocation(50,380);

    welcome.add(hi);
    welcome.add(select);
    welcome.add(login);
    welcome.add(register);
    welcome.add(un);
    welcome.add(username);
    welcome.add(pw);
    welcome.add(password);

    return welcome;
}

private JPanel homePanel() {
    JPanel home = new JPanel();
    home.setLayout(null);
    home.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JLabel hi = new JLabel("HOME");
    hi.setSize(800, 100);
    hi.setLocation(50,50);
    hi.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 48));
    hi.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    return home;

}

public void load(){

}

private void saveState(){
    Iterator<Student> it = students.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        it.next().saveStudent();
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    new mainGUI();

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==login){
        System.out.println("Logging in...");
        validateLogin(students);
    }
    else if (e.getSource()==register){

    }
}

private void validateLogin(ArrayList<Student> students){
    boolean valid = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){

        if(username.getText().equals(students.get(i).getUsername())
                && password.getText().equals(students.get(i).getPassword()))
        {   
            valid = true;
            workingStudent=(students.get(i));
            System.out.println("Successful Login!");
            cl.show(cards, "home");
        }
    }
    if(valid == false){
        System.out.println("Invalid Login, try again");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `I spent my entire Saturday trying to solve this one problem` - so why do you write hundreds of lines of code before doing any testing? Why didn't you start with something simple like a panel with a button. When you click that button then you swap to the second panel. Then that panel also has a button that swaps back to the first panel. The code will be 20-30 lines of code and it will be easy to find your errors. Then once you understand the basic concept of swapping panels you add more components/logic to each panel.

Comment: well then okay buddy, thanks a bunch, you got it. That was super helpful.... note to self: TEST STUFF YOU DONT UNDERSTAND

Comment: `note to self: TEST STUFF YOU DONT UNDERSTAND` - exactly. Write a short 20-30 line program to test a new concept. Then if it doesn't work you have something simple to post in the forum. Why do you expect us to read through 100's of lines of code to find the one mistake you may have made??? Be logical. Learn to walk before you run and you would not be wasting an entire evening trying to solve your problem. Problem solving is a skill you need to learn. Simplifying the problem will help immensely.

Comment: okay heres something nice and simple. everything in my code works. I know because I HAVE been testing, step by step.... and now I have reached a point where I cannot get the home card to show. that is my simple problem. All I wanted to know was why I can't display the home card.

Comment: and why do you expect me to read through 100's of lines of other peoples code that I usually don't understand, and then to translate that to usable information that applies to my specific problem.

Comment: No idea what 100's of lines of code you are referring to. But anyway,  you are the one trying so solve a problem. We are volunteers. If you want us to help, you make it easy for us to help you. So show you have made an effort by posting simple code that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve. Our time is precious. We can choose to use it to help your or someone else. If you make an effort we will make an effort.

Comment: And that is why I try to provide a link to the tutorial (instead of posting my own demo code whenever possible). The tutorial will generally highlight the lines of code that are important, followed by a complete working program that you can test. So the tutorial is meant to minimize reading code trying to understand every single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a JPanel that uses CardLayout, cards, but you add it to nothing, so it will of course not display itself, nor its cards. Solution: add this JPanel to your GUI.

So instead of:

```
main.setContentPane(welcomePanel());
```

do:

```
main.setContentPane(cards);
```

---

Issue number 2:

Use String constants when using Strings as a type of key. Note that you add one JPanel to the cards JPanel thusly:

```
cards.add(home, "Home");
```

But then try to display it like so:

```
cl.show(cards, "home");
```

But Home isn't the same as home.

Instead declare a constant, HOME:

```
public static final String HOME = "home";
```

and use the same constant to add the JPanel and to display it.

For a simplistic example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainGui2 extends JPanel {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private WelcomePanel welcomePanel = new WelcomePanel(this);
    private HomePanel homePanel = new HomePanel();

    public MainGui2() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(welcomePanel, WelcomePanel.NAME);
        add(homePanel, HomePanel.NAME);
    }

    public void showCard(String name) {
        cardLayout.show(this, name);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainGui2 mainPanel = new MainGui2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainGui2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}

class WelcomePanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String NAME = "welcome panel";
    private MainGui2 mainGui2;

    public WelcomePanel(final MainGui2 mainGui2) {
        this.mainGui2 = mainGui2;
        add(new JLabel(NAME));
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Logon") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainGui2.showCard(HomePanel.NAME);
            }
        }));
    }
}

class HomePanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String NAME = "home panel";

    public HomePanel() {
        add(new JLabel(NAME));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nasmarr: see edit. And listen to what camickr has to say -- debug continuously. Rather than mock him, learn to appreciate his wisdom -- I speak from experience because doing so has taught me much.

Comment: @Nasmarr: see edit for a simplistic example of what I mean.

Comment: Or you can read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Not only does it have working code for a CardLayout, but there are plenty of working examples for all Swing features. The tutorial link should be kept handy as it is a great reference that should be consulted before asking a Swing related question..