# A method with return type String that works for System.out.println(), but not if I want to use the created String in a JLabel

Tags: java, string, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

Okay so here's the deal...
I have a static object of type Student, named workingStudent.
Student has a method to return the student's name as a String.

I have a JFrame with a CardLayout JPanel that has 2 cards.
card 1 is a login screen, and upon successful login, sets workingStudent to whatever object was associated with the users account via this code..

```
private void validateLogin(ArrayList<Student> students){
    boolean valid = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){

        if(username.getText().equals(students.get(i).getUsername())
                && password.getText().equals(students.get(i).getPassword()))
        {   
            valid = true;
            setWorkingStudent(students.get(i));
            currentSemester=(students.get(i).getLastSemester());
            System.out.println("Successful Login!");
            cl.show(cards, HOMEPANEL);
            System.out.println(workingStudent.getName());
        }
    }
    if(valid == false){
        System.out.println("Invalid Login, try again");
    }

}
```

This appears to be working just fine. When this method is run, it prints out the workingStudents name with no errors. Which leads me to believe that it also sets workingStudent without any errors as well.

The problem appears in the following code, where workingStudent.getName() should be added to the JLabel's text.

```
 private JPanel homePanel() {
    JPanel home = new JPanel();
    home.setLayout(null);
    home.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JLabel hi = new JLabel("Hello, "+workingStudent.getName());
    hi.setSize(400, 100);
    hi.setLocation(10,10);
    hi.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 36));
    hi.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    home.add(hi);

    return home;

}
```

But instead, I get a NullPointerException. I'm looking for some help/any possible explanation of what could be wrong.

How is it that getName() works just fine in validateLogin() but not for homePanel()??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, and this is where I use validateLogin (it responds to a button click)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==login){
        System.out.println("Logging in...");
        validateLogin(students);
    }
    else if (e.getSource()==register){

    }
}
```

Comment: You can debug by putting null check just before using it in the JLabel?

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" an answer when you get help on your previous questions by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113406/implementing-cardlayout-within-a-jframe-and-switching-cards-based-on-specific-bu#34113419

Comment: even when I do System.out.println(workingStudent.getName() just before it is used in the JLabel, it still prints out.

Comment: @camickr sorry I'm new! I have to learn the StackOverflow manners

Comment: It seems like no references to workingStudent work within homePanel(). I don't get it -_-

Comment: *"I have a static object.."*  Why is it `static`?  That sounds more like a potential problem, than a solution.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `home.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your program invokes homePanel method before workingStudent variable created. Try modify your code this way:

```
private JPanel homePanel() {
    JPanel home = new JPanel();
    home.setLayout(null);
    home.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    String greeting = 
      workingStudent==null?"Hello, unknown user":"Hello, "+workingStudent.getName();
    JLabel hi = new JLabel(greeting);
    hi.setSize(400, 100);
    hi.setLocation(10,10);
    hi.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 36));
    hi.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    home.add(hi);

    return home;

}
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try this immediately. But just so you know, all of this code belongs to one class called mainGUI and I declared workingStudent variable at the beginning of this class before homePanel or any methods are invoked. Also keep in my mind that I have no issues printing strings from workingStudent if it is printed to standard output.