# How do i show different JFrame for employee or manager depending on the login information

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, netbeans

ok am creating a java application on netbeans with mysql database on sqlworkbench, i created a login jframe and a login table in the database . to check wether username and password exit in database or not and it proceeds if true and shows the employee jframe for example. how can i make it show a different jframe for the manger if he/she enters their username and password . like i should add a column to the table of the login info that determines wether this account for employee or manager . but when clicking on the button on the login jframe how its going to know ? like should i except such a query but how its going to compare then show for example if jframe for employee was named jframe1 and jframe for manager was jframe2

```
        String sql;
        String S=jTextField1.getText();
        String S1=jPasswordField1.getText();
        String S3=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        sql="SELECT * from user_pass where username='"+S+"' and password='"+S1+"' and type='"+S3+"'";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next()){
```

Comment: Swap views with a CardLayout, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113406/implementing-cardlayout-within-a-jframe-and-switching-cards-based-on-specific-bu). You could use the same String for login type as you do for CardLayout show constant, or use a Map to Map Strings as needed.

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: Essentially you need several things, you need away to determine what the user can do, you could create a user object as part of the validation process or query the database with the I'd of the user (which could be returned from you validator). You then need to use some kind of controller to decided which views the user should be presented with. This moves you into the realms of MVC which could allow you to define a navigation model of both the user and manager which would reduce the amount of code duplication, decouple the code and increase your code reuse ability

Comment: Agree with @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 4):

You can try a solution like the one below.  The code is incomplete but will get you to your solution.

```
public class MySqlApp extends JFrame
{
    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    JPanel employee = new JPanel();
    JPanel manager = new JPanel();

    public MySqlApp()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main.setLayout(cardLayout);
        main.add(employee, "employee");
        main.add(manager, "manager");

        add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        String sql="SELECT * from user_pass where username='"+S+"' and password='"+S1+"' and type='"+S3+"'";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next())
        {
            if("manager".equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("AccountType")))
            {
                cardLayout.show(main, "manager");
            }
            else
            {
                cardLayout.show(main, "employee");
            }
        }
    }
}
```